# Rackspace Red Hat 5.4 converted to CentOS repository, mod_ssl will not install

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, mod-ssl

I am trying to add mod_ssl to apache, but it fails due to the repository change to CentOS as we needed a newer version of imagemagick, which was only available on CentOS.  I am now getting the following error...

```
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.

Error Message:
    Your account does not have access to any channels matching (release='5', arch='x86_64-redhat-linux')
Error Class Code: 19
Error Class Info: Architecture and OS version combination is not supported.
Explanation: 
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and
     details on how to reproduce this problem.
```

How would I go around this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can deal with this. This does not look like you converted the server from RHEL to CentOS. Honestly, you may just be better off downloading the packages you need from a CentOS repository and mannually installing them.

As for the error, it doesn't look as though you have Red Hat support anymore. You could actually convert the system to CentOS by following this guide:

Migration from RHEL5 to CentOS5

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide

Comment: I was able to individually install the packages after I downgraded the Apache install.